# App Store Submission - Missing code signing entitlement

Tags: ios, app-store, code-signing, code-signing-entitlements

[image: error msg]

Hello Univers.
I have a problem when i achieve this app for submission to app store...
in my app i create my own static library and use private cocoa pods for manage libs and in my static libs i have a bundle resource embedded.

In my app project i can use my static lib and bundle pods without problems. But when i achieve to submit to app store. i found error about code sign and entitlements in bundle resource?

How do I fix this?

Thank for answer.

Sorry for my english:D

### Edited

**Solve this issue**

> When you build bundle target Xcode 6 generate exec file and plist
>   embeded in your bundle and it no code signing...

**You have 3 solution**

1. Adding the `–deep` flag to “Other Code Signing Flags” (OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS)
2. Delete Info.plist inside the bundle if it’s only a resource package.
   (And if there’s some reason you need it, at least delete the ‘CFBundleExecutable’ key.)
3. Right click on bundle > Show package contents > Remove Unix Exec File > Awesome!

Comment: I'm having the same issue no idea what to do about it.. hope you get an answer

Comment: Yesterday.. i can solve this issue. because when you build bundle target Xcode 6 generate exec file and plist embeded in your bundle and it no code signing...
You have 3 solution
1. Adding the `–deep` flag to “Other Code Signing Flags” (OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS)
2. Delete Info.plist inside the bundle if it’s only a resource package.
(And if there’s some reason you need it, at least delete the ‘CFBundleExecutable’ key.)
3. Right click on bundle > Show package contents > Remove Unix Exec File > Awesome!

Comment: Third option did the trick